# bootstrap images inside columns not displaying properly in for loop php

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, width

i have a bootstrap page where i am trying to display images inside bootstrap columns, i did the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="row">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=19;$i++){?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4" style="text-align:center">
      <img src="n<?=$i?>.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>



  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

there are 19 images, everything is coming fine except the 7th image which is coming in a single row in large screens. this is the live link:[enter link description here](https://thenoshbistro.com/menu/)

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code uses bootstrap 3, so flexbox is not used by default.

**Bootstrap V3:**

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=19;$i++){?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4" style="text-align:center">
      <img src="n<?=$i?>.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Better to use bootstarp v4 or v5 with flexbox support so there is no need for the extra CSS.

**Bootstrap V4 and V5:**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=19;$i++){?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4" style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="n<?=$i?>.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this, but it makes all the images in one line

Comment: Oh, my bad!! Just edited the code.